# When using Sqlite3 on Electron app , streams are undefined - Node's set-blocking module

Tags: sqlite, stream, webpack

We are working on a universal app, that must execute on mobile (ios, android), desktop (windows, mac, linux) adn in any browser.

For client database management, we want to use sqlite3 - for desktop- , in this case the app will be packaged using Electron (Atom shell) . The module bundler we are using is webpack, as the app is developed with Ionic 2 and Angular2.

We have installed sqlite3 well, as a project dependency, with node-pre-gyp generating the binary for the platform (in this case we are testing with Windows 7 64 bits)

We have a provider for Sqlite3, this is the code:

```
import * as sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';

import { IDatabaseProvider } from './database.provider';


export class Sqlite3DatabaseProvider implements IDatabaseProvider {

    private _storage;

    constructor() {
        console.log('Initializing Sqlite3 Database Provider');
    }

    openDatabase() {
        this._storage =  new sqlite3.Database('v2App_sqlite3.db');
    }
}
```

As you can notice, the line the creates a database is commented, as the app works OK like that. If I uncomment that line , we have this error:

```
Runtime Error
Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:210758:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:210757:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12580:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12873:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69457:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69638:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:211548:72)
```

The curious of this, is that it's failing here, in the code of the set-blocking npm module:

```
module.exports = function (blocking) {
  [process.stdout, process.stderr].forEach(function (stream) {
    if (stream._handle && stream.isTTY && typeof stream._handle.setBlocking === 'function') {
      stream._handle.setBlocking(blocking)
    }
  })
}
```

As stream is coming undefined ,when getting the _handle property gives the error.

But this code is only executed if I add the line that creates the sqlite3 database:

```
this._storage =  new sqlite3.Database('v2App_sqlite3.db');
```

What is the relation between this module (set-blocking ) and sqlite3 ?, Why the streams are undefined when trying to create the sqlite3 database ?

Maybe  as generates a file - the database - , using Node's outputStream, and still could not have been created that object - stream.

Any help?

Thanks in advance